# php function calling stops the program. ( it was issue with array declaration method )

Tags: php, function, ubuntu

One of my tiny program works smoothly on my lamp on pc. but when i did it on ubuntu vps, it rejects some pages or rejects some methods. Please help.

```
<?php
function Calc_ttlpay() {
$conn1 = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'mbimbi1979', 'men');
if (!$conn1) {
die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$TTLsal=[];
$stmtTTL =$conn1->prepare("SELECT netsal FROM total_sif_view WHER Year
=?and month ? and visa = ? ");

$param1 = $_POST['year'];
$param2 = $_POST['month'];
$param3 = $_POST['visa'];

$stmtTTL->bind_param('sss',$param1,$param2,$param3);    
$stmtTTL->execute();
$stmtTTL->store_result();
$TTLsal[1]=$stmtTTL->num_rows;
$TTL=0;

$stmtTTL->bind_result($ntsl);

while ($cresult=$stmtTTL->fetch()) {
$TTL=$TTL+$ntsl;    


}
$TTLsal[0]=$TTL;
return $TTLsal;
}
```

Comment: I called the function like $TTsal=Calc_ttlpay(); . My PC lamp work with this smoothly. But if i try with ubuntu vps server, i dont get the balance portion of html elements even after this function calling. Please somebody help.

Comment: @DanielA.White the page give blank page or sever rejects it.

Comment: Are you sure all characters match not only in a case insensitive, but also in a case sensitive manner?

Comment: @LajosArpad it works on my LAMP windows server. Only issue with Ubuntu VPS. Can be a difference in apache requirements or php requirements of the vps ?

Comment: Bineesh, you completely ignored my question. It is difficult to help you this way.

Comment: @LajosArpad honestly i didnt understand what you asked; in which part of code you referred it. But i wanted to specify the problem was only when i moved the files to my production server ie a small ubuntu vps. Thanks for your words.

Comment: @LajosArpad the error was with array declaration method. You couldnt find that, still you VOTED me -ve. Its so bad and rude.

Comment: I did not downvote you. I was only asking a question and you called me rude. You have a lot to learn, pal.

Comment: @LajosArpad in that case im guilty and feel sorry.

Comment: @Bineesh, no problems, but we should not assume about each-other that the other cannot answer a given question. Also, down-votes can prove to be useful if they are explained, as they might show flaws we make while writing posts. No need to feel bad about them. Off course, there are some people who down-vote you because you criticize their favorite technology, or do not like you. It is better to ignore those people. It seems that your error was with initiating the array. You have answered this question, you should accept your answer to let others know about the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Debug and it will tell you.

In your PHP file at the top after the opening `<?php` paste the code from below to turn on error reporting:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

If the above does not work on the server environment please put this into a php.ini file:

```
display_errors = on
```

See what if any errors that gives you. If something is missing it should tell you  :)

Also try view source on the page as that can sometimes display where it breaks and why.

Comment: Thanks for this life saving reply. But still not resolved, trying to change the server php.ini and looking or error messages if any caught. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Thank you soo much. Actually i had some errors in defining arrays. The method i used in test server enviro.. is not suitable for the production sever ie  $someVar = [ ] ; dont worked on that ubuntu php. So i made it like =array(); now everthing is okay.

Answer (score 1):

I had some errors in defining arrays. The method I used in test server enviro.. is not suitable for the production server, i.e.,`$someVar = [ ] ;` don't work on that Ubuntu PHP. So I made it like `=array();` now everything is okay.